# No bean named 'CamelBeanParameterMappingStrategy' available

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Springboot camel application. Below error is seen in dynatrace.

No bean named 'CamelBeanParameterMappingStrategy' available

Comment: Any stack trace with that?  Somehow you got down into `BeanConstants` and the code asked for `BEAN_PARAMETER_MAPPING_STRATEGY`.  This returns `CamelBeanParameterMappingStrategy`, and from what I can tell, does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for checking this issue. Using Camel version 2.19. Do not understand from where the call is going to it. Is there a way to set the BeanParameterMappingStrategy in Camel?

Answer (score 0):

Within the BeanInfo class of Apache Camel the ParameterMappingStrategy is resolved by looking in the registry (see below)

```
Registry registry = camelContext.getRegistry();    
ParameterMappingStrategy answer = registry.lookupByNameAndType(BeanConstants.BEAN_PARAMETER_MAPPING_STRATEGY, ParameterMappingStrategy.class);
```

So yes, you can create your own version and add it to the registry